# Need help translating "of" in the bible (genitive case)

Tags: greek

I don't know much about Greek, but apparently when the word "of" is used, it's usually a noun in the genitive case. But since the genitive can be used several different ways, just like "of" can in English, I'm having some trouble.

For example, does "The love of God" mean 1: God's love, 2: Godly love, or 3: love for God? How can I tell? Is it purely context based?

Specifically I noticed that in Romans the phrases "gospel of God" and "gospel of Christ" are both used, and I was thinking that "of God" is showing source, and "of Christ" is the subject matter, as in, the gospel concerning Christ, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an example that shows ἡ ἀγάπη τοῦ Θεοῦ in a context that suggests "godly love" or "love for God" could be used?

Comment: The phrase 'faith of Christ' is ambiguous in English. It can mean either 'that which is believed about Christ' or it can mean 'the faith that Jesus had in God'. So I can see what the Questioner is getting at.

Comment: @NigelJ I think that might be more of a theological thing.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think this question is too broad. Perhaps you could provide an example you're having trouble with. I think Mark 11:22 would be a good one. It would take a very long answer to explain why and how the genitive is translated in every situation.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but please take the "tour."  Questions about the biblical languages as such are not appropriate for this site.  It would be better to find a specific verse which can be understood in more than one way, and then ask if grammar helps determine the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The original (1550 Stephens) of Luke 2:7 reads :

> και ετεκεν τον υιον αυτης τον προτοτοκον

which the KJV translates :

> and she brought forth her firsborn son,

in which the word 'son' takes the form of a possessive genetive, 'Mary's firstborn son,' but which does not give weight to the second definite article.

But it can also be translated :

> and she brought forth the Son, of her, the Prototokos,

in which the 'of' is not a matter of possession, but of origin; and in which the word προτοτοκον is given a place meaning 'first token' rather than firstborn -
highlighting the meaning of τοκος, usury (Young and KJV), and, thus, the meaning of 'the first token of a successful investment'.

Thayer's Greek Lexicon :

> τόκος - 2. interest of money, usury (because it multiplies money, and as it were 'breeds'

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you're asking. To Paul, I don't think there is a difference between "the gospel of God", "the gospel of Christ", or "the gospel of me". They are all the same story, or the same "good news".

Of course, God is the source of all things, so Paul most certainly considered Him the source of this gospel. Likewise, Paul believed Christ spoke to him directly through divine revelation, so Christ is the source of Paul's gospel. And since nobody knew this gospel except for Paul, he is also the source.

All three *possess* this gospel, and it is the same *kind* of gospel, therefore Paul uses the genitive.